# Finer control of KOMA-Script Table of Contents alignment

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, alignment, tocloft, titletoc

This is really a multi-part question largely related to getting the table of contents style to match an established style. I'm attaching screenshots below of 1) my current status and 2) the example style I'm trying to match.

I am using KOMA-Script for section and table of contents control, but there are a few things that I can't get to work the way I want them to:

1. I'm using `dynnumwidth=true`, but what I really want is for the section titles to simply be adjacent to the numbers separated by some standard length (e.g., 1em). As it currently stands, the dynamic width is being set by the section numbering for "Informative Appendix A".
2. I haven't found an equivalent `dynpagenumberwidth` option, but again, I just want the page numbers to be right-aligned with the dot-fill spanning straight up to the number.
3. In general, is there a way to "`RedeclareTOCStyleEntry`" for a specific subset of the sections?
4. (Lower priority) Is there a way to make a tighter dot-fill?

**Update:** I am also open to solutions that accomplish the same objective with `tocloft` or `titletoc`/`titlesec`.

## My Current Output:

> [image]

## Example Style:

> [image]

## Minimal Input to Reproduce

```latex
\documentclass[
  twoside,
  fontsize=10pt,
  paper=letter]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\KOMAoptions{numbers=noenddot}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indent=0em, numwidth=2.5em, pagenumberwidth=5em, beforeskip=0em,dynnumwidth=true, entryformat=\sffamily\large,pagenumberformat=\sffamily\large,linefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill]{tocline}{section}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indent=1em, numwidth=2.5em, pagenumberwidth=5em, beforeskip=0em,dynnumwidth=true, entryformat=\sffamily\large,pagenumberformat=\sffamily\large,linefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill]{tocline}{subsection}
\setkomafont{section}{\sffamily\large\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\normalsize\normalfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\normalsize\normalfont\bfseries}
\setkomafont{paragraph}{\normalsize\normalfont\bfseries}


\begin{document}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{\centering\sffamily{\large\textbf{Contents}}\par}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\section*{Foreword}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Foreword}

\clearpage
\section{Section}

\section{Another Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\clearpage
\appendix

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{Informative Appendix \Alph{section}\quad}
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{\MakeUppercase{\thesection}}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\Alph{section}\arabic{subsection}}

\section{Appendix 1}

\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{RS0001-\arabic{page}}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{RS0001\quad}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{RS0001.\arabic{subsection}\quad}

\section{Specification 0001}

\subsection{Identification and History}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want the subsections to be excluded (like in the example) or included (like in your output)? If you want them to be included, how do you want to align them? Also, could you show the code for what you have achieved so far?

Comment: I would like the subsections to be included with numbers indented as shown in my current output, but with the subsection titles adjacent to the numbers separated by some defined spacing.

I am working on a minimal example of the code to help illustrate.

Comment: @schoekling I've added the minimal example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` to define new TOC entries. Then you can redefine `\addsectiontocentry` and `\addsubsectiontocentry` and use these new TOC entries in the appendix and the specifications. Then `dynnumwidth` can still be used.

```latex
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
\KOMAoptions{numbers=noenddot}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\BeforeTOCHead[toc]{\renewcommand*{\raggedsection}{\centering}}% <- centered TOC heading
\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subsectiontocdepth}

% clone level, indent, numwidth of the section entry
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  level:=section,
  indent:=section,
  numwidth:=section
]{tocline}{appsec,rssec}
% clone level, indent, numwidth of the subsection entry
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indent=1em]{tocline}{subsection}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  level:=subsection,
  indent:=subsection,
  numwidth:=subsection
]{tocline}{rssubsec}

% set dynnumwidth, pagenumberbox=\mbox etc. for all entries
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  numwidth=1em,
  dynnumwidth,
  beforeskip=0em,
  entryformat=\usekomafont{tocentry},
  pagenumberformat=\usekomafont{tocentry},
  linefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill,
  pagenumberbox=\mbox
]{tocline}{section,appsec,rssec,subsection,rssubsec}

%appsec: needs colon after number
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entryformat={\def\autodot{:}\usekomafont{tocentry}}
]{tocline}{appsec}

% change the dotsep in TOC
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@dotsep}{1.5}% default is 4.5
\makeatother

% font settings
\setkomafont{section}{\large}% <- changed
\setkomafont{subsection}{\normalsize\normalfont\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\normalsize\normalfont\bfseries}
\setkomafont{paragraph}{\normalsize\normalfont\bfseries}
\newkomafont{tocentry}{\sffamily\large}

% uppercased section headings
\newcommand*{\originalsectionlinesformat}{}
\let\originalsectionlinesformat\sectionlinesformat
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \Ifstr{#1}{section}
    {\originalsectionlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}{\MakeUppercase{#4}}}
    {\originalsectionlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
}

% allow a prefix for section numbers (needed in appendix)
\newcommand*{\sectionprefix}{}
\newcommand*{\originalsectionformat}{}
\let\originalsectionformat\sectionformat
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
  \Ifstr{\sectionprefix}{}
    {\originalsectionformat}
    {\MakeUppercase{\sectionprefix}\thesection:\enskip}%
}

\newcommand*\appendixmore{%
  \clearpage
  \renewcommand*{\sectionprefix}{Informative Appendix~}%
  \renewcommand*{\addsectiontocentry}[2]{%
    \addtocentrydefault{appsec}{\sectionprefix##1}{##2}%
  }
}

\newcommand*{\preinitsectionhook}[1]{}
\AddtoDoHook{heading/preinit/section}{\preinitsectionhook}
\newcommand*{\RS}{%
  \setcounter{section}{0}
  \renewcommand*{\sectionprefix}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\thesection}{RS%
    \ifnum\value{section}<1000 0\fi
    \ifnum\value{section}<100 0\fi
    \ifnum\value{section}<10 0\fi
    \arabic{section}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\preinitsectionhook}[1]{%
    \cleardoubleoddpage% <- odd page numbers must be on right pages!!
    \setcounter{page}{1}%
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\thesection-\arabic{page}}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\addsectiontocentry}[2]{%
    \addtocentrydefault{rssec}{##1}{##2}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\addsubsectiontocentry}[2]{%
    \addtocentrydefault{rssubsec}{##1}{##2}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\addsec{Foreword}% <- changed
\Blindtext
\clearpage
\blinddocument
\blinddocument

\appendix
\section{Appendix 1}
\subsection{Subappendix 1}
\Blindtext
\section{Appendix 2}
\blindtext
\subsection{Another Subappendix}
\Blindtext

\RS
\section{Specification 0001}
\subsection{Identification and History}
\Blindtext
\subsection{More infos}
\Blindtext

\section{Specification 0002}
\subsection{Identification and History}
\Blindtext[30]
\subsection{More infos}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Additional remarks:

1. If you change the value of the page counter in a twosided document, ensure that odd page numbers are on right pages. Therefore use `\cleardoubleoddpage` (or at least `\cleardoublepage`) before `\setcounter{page}{1}`.
2. Do not use `\MakeUppercase` in the argument of `\setkomafont` or `\addtokomafont`, because it is not a font command.
3. Do not use format (`\centering`) or font (`\sffamily`) commands  in the definition of `\contentsname`.
4. `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is only needed with old TeX-distributions.

Comment: It took me a while to realize that if you are using a hyperref TOC, you also need to use `\renewcommand*{\theHsection}{\thesection}` within the `\RS` command, otherwise the RS sections will link to the corresponding indices instead.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I came up with based on your minimal input and the example style image:

[image]

Probably not the most elegant way, but I hope it fits your needs. All you have to do within `document` is to switch the content type by using `\appendices` and `\specifications`

**The Code**:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}

\KOMAoptions{numbers=noenddot}

% Only needed for demonstration
    \usepackage{blindtext} 

% The TOC entries (almost) like you defined them
    \DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
        indent=0em,%
        numwidth=1em,%
        pagenumberwidth=1em,%
        beforeskip=0em,%
        entryformat=\sffamily\large,%
        pagenumberformat=\sffamily\large,%
        linefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill
    ]{tocline}{section}
    
    \DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
        indent=1em,%
        numwidth=2em,%
        pagenumberwidth=1em,%
        beforeskip=0em,%
        entryformat=\sffamily\large,%
        pagenumberformat=\sffamily\large
    ]{tocline}{subsection}

% Tight dots
    \makeatletter
        \renewcommand\@dotsep{.}
    \makeatother

% Your headings untouched
    \setkomafont{section}{\sffamily\large\MakeUppercase}
        \renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
    \setkomafont{subsection}{\normalsize\normalfont\bfseries}
        \renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
    \setkomafont{subsubsection}{\normalsize\normalfont\bfseries}
    \setkomafont{paragraph}{\normalsize\normalfont\bfseries}


% Switch command for appendix, similar to \frontmatter, \mainmatter, etc.
    \newcommand{\appendices}{%
        \clearpage\appendix
            
        \renewcommand*{\thesection}{Informative Appendix \Alph{section}:}
        \renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{\MakeUppercase{\thesection}\enskip}
        \renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\Alph{section}\arabic{subsection}}
        
        \addtocontents{toc}{%
            \DeclareTOCStyleEntry[dynnumwidth]{tocline}{section}}
    }

% Switch command for the specifications
    \newcommand{\specifications}{%
        \clearpage\appendix
        \setcounter{page}{1}
    
        \renewcommand*{\thesection}{RS%
            \ifnum\value{section}<1000 0\fi%
            \ifnum\value{section}<100 0\fi%
            \ifnum\value{section}<10 0\fi%
            \arabic{section}}
        \renewcommand{\thepage}{\thesection-\arabic{page}}
        \renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
        
        \addtocontents{toc}{%
            \DeclareTOCStyleEntry[dynnumwidth=false,numwidth=4em,pagenumberwidth=4.5em]{tocline}{section}
            \DeclareTOCStyleEntry[numwidth=5em,pagenumberwidth=4.5em]{tocline}{subsection}}
    }


\begin{document}

%   The TOC
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
    \renewcommand*{\contentsname}{\centering\sffamily{\large\textbf{Contents}}\par}
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
    
%   This is a shorter version for your \section*{Foreword}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Foreword}  
    \addsec{Foreword}
    \clearpage
    
%   Filling up the TOC
    \blinddocument
    \blinddocument
    
\appendices
    
    \section{An Appendix}
    \clearpage
    
    \section{Another Appendix}  

\specifications
    
    \section{Liquid-Cooled Chiller} 
    \subsection{Identification and History}
    \clearpage
    
    \section{Specification 0002}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is much more elegant than the solution I came up with (which was to `DeclareNewSectionCommand`s for appendix and specification sections [levels 1-4], each with their own `toc` settings). So the trick to "`RedeclareTOCStyleEntry`" is to include the `DeclareTOCStyleEntry` inside an `\addtocontents`. That's not covered in the KOMA docs at all. Do these inherit the previously established values, or completely redefine them?

Two other questions:

1. Why not always use `dynnumwidth=true`?
2. Is the `\appendix` command here doing anything except restart the section counter?

Comment: 1. if you always use ``dynnumwidth=true``, you'll experience exactly what you saw in your question, namely all the ``sectionentry``s aligning according to the longest number (i.e. 'informative appendix X'). 2. No, since we're redefining ``\thesection`` afterwards anyways.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the first question. The ``DeclareTOCStyleEntry``s only change the values spcified, that's why I had to use ``dynnumwidth=false`` inside ``\specifications``.